Is there a Snack-like tool for Flutter as there is for React Native?
I am porting a React Native app to Flutter. I love being able to post a problem using a Snack or in my teaching to provide Snacks to my students or readers to demonstrate some language feature. But I have tried to find the equivalent for Flutter and failed.  In some of the documentation for Flutter I see examples of a "Run" button to run the code much like in RN documentation using Snack.
But try as I might I cannot find it for Flutter. I have tried at least 20-30 different google searches. This Github thread seems to say there is nothing (last updated 9/2023(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29021) but Flutter documentation seems to be able to do it.

DartPad.dev is a beautiful tool for showcasing Dart and Flutter without needing to install anything locally. It has support for Flutter/Dart packages. This is because Flutter has web support and can be ran in the browser. There are limitations where not all packages may work because the packages may require native (Android/iOS) hooks.
Flutter Docs include a Widget Index which showcases all the widgets available and most pages include a video and DartPad.
Here is a sample of rendering a cool sunflower in DartPad.dev https://dartpad.dev/?sample=sunflower
DartPad allows for sharing examples using Github Gists which is discussed in the Sharing Guide

Thanks - but I was looking for something like Snack. Flutter for the Web is so different from everything else. Snack can be run on an actual device. You can play audio files - use bluetooth headsets. Visually Dartpad provides a very different look than an iPhone or iPad or Android.

Oh I understand. I would not say that Flutter Web is so different, there are a lot of packages that do work on Web which would work on DartPad.

Yes - that is a clearer way to say it - "there are a lot of packages that do work on the Web." If you are trying to learn phone/tablet layout or create a design for a team however, I am not convinced that DartPad for the Web is useful. With Snack - co-workers can see the layout on their phone so simply.
